# How To Implement api service counter in MVC 4 web api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am using asp.net mvc4 web api. I want a counter that counts the number of requests made by a user in particular time. if with in that time number of requests exceed the threshold value, user should be blocked for some time.
As I am new in this field please suggest me the way to implement this.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? I would probably implement this using an ActionFilter. Take some time to read this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Moeri Yes I know about Message Handlers and Action Filters. What I am trying to do is getting request cookies every time setting the time and counter and add them back in response. but I don,t think it is a good solution. Please suggest.

Comment: Please tell me the way how to do it.

Comment: I advise against using a cookie to do this. A user would be able to edit the cookie values before it's sent back to you, rendering your counter useless. The best way would be to store the users count in a database and check it whenever the user requests your api using an action filter.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to store the timestamps of each request in a database and query it each time a user makes a request to get the total and then return a 403 (forbidden) when it has exceeded it's limit.